# Use jQuery to change CSS on OTHER divs

Tags: jquery, css, fade

OK so basically  have 3 divs, all stacked vertically. Each has its own class assigned (.inner1, .inner2 and .inner3) What I'd like to have happen is when you mouse over one of them, the other 2 fade out to 40% transparent. Each would have the ability to fade the others out. Mouse over #1, and #2 and 3 fade out. Mouse over #2, and #1 and 3 fade out...does that make sense?

Thanks very much guys!

Comment: It does not make sense unless you show some code and what you have tried.. This is not a homework site where ppl get the work done for you. We can try to resolve the issue if you tried something and stuck at a certain point

Comment: what you have tried???

http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: i think all are here to give tutorial. Great SO change its policy .. strange :D

Comment: Let Us Know What You Have Tried ??

Answer (score 3):

For starters this should do

You can use the `mouseover` and `mouseleave` events along with `animate`

```
$('[class*=inner]').on({
    mouseover : function() {
        $('[class*=inner]').not(this).animate({opacity : 0.4},1000);
    },
    mouseleave : function() {
        $('[class*=inner]').not(this).animate({opacity : 1},1000);
    }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J8KDv/8/)**

Comment: Thats very cool! I should mention though that the 3 divs are contained within another div with INNER in its class, and I also have a few other divs with INNER as part of their titles too. That seems to make a mess of the code when I posted it here: http://jsfiddle.net/J8KDv/11/

Comment: @JeffMonk That is because `<div class="inner_content">` causes problems as `$('[class*=inner]')` selects even the outer div.  Just change it's class to not include `inner` and it should get the work done

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$("div[class^='inner']").on('mouseover',function(){
     var selected_div = $(this);
     $("div[class^='inner']").not(this).each(function(){
              $(this).fadeOut('slow');  //you can apply any other animation effects   
     });
});
```

Assumed that you need to display them on `mouseleave`

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the ones before:

```
$("div[class^='inner']").on('mouseover',function(){
     var div = $(this);
     $("div[class^='inner']").not(this).each(function(){
          $(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.4);
     });
});

$("div[class^='inner']").on('mouseout',function(){
     $("div[class^='inner']").not(this).each(function(){
          $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
     });
});
```

Example here: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tYM9G/)